# Употребление слов: "частный извоз" и "извозчик"

Tags: этимология

В вопросе про приказчика подняли тему и другого слова "извозчик". Собственно говоря, им и до сих пор пользуются. Нашла ссылку вот: [Частный извозчик...](http://www.baltinfo.ru/2012/06/14/Chastnyi-izvozchik-lishilsya-zdorovya-i-mashiny-na-Belorusskoi-284672) Мне это слово нравится, понятное. Или имеется ввиду, что таксист он и есть таксист, а если частник, то извозчик?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну в принципе понятие частного извоза никто не отменял, а значит и извозчик вполне может быть. Вот только зачем противопоставлять его таксисту? Таксист при таком подходе тоже извозчик, только лицензированный предприятием, а не государством.